# mysql i got duplicates data

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables one is film and another is film_votes total 23 record.

please see the below screen shot for film table structure
[image]

below is the film_votes table structure

[image]

i want to show all record of user_id=8163 and order by year desc in film table 'ano' column treated as year.

I use limit per page 12 record that means pagination is there. but when i run some record are duplicate in page two

below are my code

```
$memID = 8163;
SELECT a.cartel,a.cartel_es,a.cartel_vo,a.titulo_es,a.titulo,a.titulo_url,a.fecha_es,a.genero,a.ano,b.user_id,b.movie_id,b.rating FROM film a, film_votes b WHERE a.peli_id=b.movie_id AND b.user_id=$memID  ORDER BY a.ano DESC LIMIT 0,12



SELECT a.cartel,a.cartel_es,a.cartel_vo,a.titulo_es,a.titulo,a.titulo_url,a.fecha_es,a.genero,a.ano,b.user_id,b.movie_id,b.rating FROM film a, film_votes b WHERE a.peli_id=b.movie_id AND b.user_id=$memID  ORDER BY a.ano DESC LIMIT 12,12
```

i don't why this happen and why duplicate records are coming in page two

please suggest me how to fix this issue and what mistake i did.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the different between you two codes? There seems to be the same :-)

Comment: You need `LIMIT 12,12` for second page.

Comment: Both the codes are same. That's why you get duplicates.

Comment: @Shaiful Islam and Praveen Kumar yes, i did mistake while ad question but in real the limit is 0,12 and 12,12

Answer (score 3):

For the second page, you need to use this:

```
SELECT a.cartel,a.cartel_es,a.cartel_vo,a.titulo_es,a.titulo,a.titulo_url,a.fecha_es,a.genero,a.ano,b.user_id,b.movie_id,b.rating FROM film a, film_votes b
    WHERE a.peli_id=b.movie_id AND b.user_id=$memID
    ORDER BY a.ano DESC
    LIMIT 12, 12
```

The `LIMIT` is the key here. The syntax is:

```
LIMIT [Start], [Length]
```

Comment: i have a mistake while ask question but in real the limit is 0,12 and 12,12

Comment: Oops, okay, lemme check your question again and give you a better `LEFT JOIN` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SQL LEFT JOIN?

Something like:

```
SELECT a.cartel,a.cartel_es,a.cartel_vo,a.titulo_es,a.titulo,a.titulo_url,a.fecha_es,a.genero,a.ano,b.user_id,b.movie_id,b.rating
FROM film a
LEFT JOIN film_votes b
ON a.peli_id=b.movie_id 
WHERE b.user_id=$memID 
ORDER BY a.ano DESC LIMIT 0,12;
```

and change

DESC LIMIT 12, 12 and so on 24, 12 as you proceed to the next page.

More info: [SQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: do you think left join will work there? left join means fetch record from left table 

if we user table1 left join table2 then fetch all match record from table1

but i need to fetch all matched record from both table

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are executing same code for all page. so you need to do little dynamic.Like this

```
$page=1;//receive the page number.lets assume 1 for first page 2 for 2nd page
//$page=$_GET['page'];you can receive it this way 

$start=($page-1)*12;//calculate starting index
```

//now make your query like this

```
SELECT a.cartel,a.cartel_es,a.cartel_vo,a.titulo_es,a.titulo,a.titulo_url,a.fecha_es,a.genero,a.ano,b.user_id,b.movie_id,b.rating FROM film a, film_votes b WHERE a.peli_id=b.movie_id AND b.user_id=$memID  ORDER BY a.ano DESC LIMIT $start,12
```